# lseek function problem in a copy file program!

Tags: c, file, text-files

Got to use lseek function in this program below... Program is simply copying file (that already exist). I wanned to copy the existing file with the chars from the end of file
for example: Sorce_File.txt contains:"1 2 3" after copy Target_File.txt contains:"3 2 1"

I'm pretty sure it's simple problem but couldn't find out since 2 days how to do it

```
   #include <fcntl.h>

   #include <stdio.h>

   #define MAX 512

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 char buf[MAX];
 int desc_sorc, desc_targ;
 int lbajt;

 if (argc<3){
  argv[0];
    exit(1);
 }

 desc_sorc = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (desc_sorc == -1){

 }

 desc_targ = creat(argv[2], 0640);
 if (desc_targ == -1){
  exit(1);
  }

 while((lbajt = read(desc_sorc, buf, MAX)) > 0){

  if (lbajt ==  -1) {
    perror("position error");
    exit(1);}

  if (write(desc_targ, buf, lbajt) == -1)

{
   exit(1);


    }
  } 
 if (lbajt == -1){
    exit(1);
 } 

 if (close(desc_sorc) == -1 || close(desc_targ) == -1){
    exit(1);
 }

 exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: It would be easier with a question and the proper code indentation...

Comment: Homework?  Looks like there is a lot of code missing, and I don't see `lseek` in the code you pasted.

Comment: true ... there is no lseek code passed. Because not sure where exactly should I put it in. I did that before function "write"  ... The missing part of code is just the code comments ... Do not know much about C

Comment: *before function "write" but didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  int desc_sorc, desc_targ;
> ```

You don't actually initialize these to anything. Anywhere.

EDIT: Now that you've fixed that, have you actually tested it again?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the equivalent of `strrev(...)` in there to reverse the string you write out as well starting from the end of the source file and reading backwards or writing from the end of the target file back to the beginning.

The actual implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.